The equation $x^3=u$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ if and only if $x^3 \equiv u \mod p$ has a solution.
Let $p \neq 3, p \in \mathbb{P}$ and $u \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ . The equation $x^3=u$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ if and only if $x^3 \equiv u \mod p$ has a solution.
My Approach:
Suppose $x^3=u$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$. We have to show that $x^3 \equiv u \mod p$ has a solution.
$\mathbb{Z}_p$ is defined as
$\mathbb{Z}_p=\{ \overline{x_k} \in \prod_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}/p^{k+1}\mathbb{Z}: x_{k+1} \equiv x_k \mod p^{k+1} \}$.
Further $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}=\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus p \mathbb{Z}_p$. This means we need to show that if $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p\setminus p \mathbb{Z}_p$, then $x^3 \equiv u \mod p$. But how do I do that?
I thought of the following (that sounds wrong):
$x^3 \equiv u \mod p$ is equivalent to $p | u-x^3$. Since $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p\setminus p \mathbb{Z}_p$, $x^3$ can't be a multiple of $p$, thus $x^3 \not \equiv u \mod p$.
But that's the opposite of what I wanted to show.
My question is, how does one do the proof (both directions)?

Edit:
Hensel Lemma:
Suppose $f \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. Let $l:=\nu_p(f'(x_0))$. If $f(x_0) \equiv 0 \mod p^{2l+1}$, then there exists $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$  such that $f(x)=0$ and $x \equiv x_0 \mod p^{l+1}$.
Now define $f(x):=x^3-u$, then $x^3=u$ to have a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ means that there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $f(x_0)=0$.
$f'=3x^2$, thus $f'(x_0)=3x_0^2$
$\nu_p(3x_0^2)=\nu_p(3)+2\nu_p(x_0)$
Now since $p \neq 3$, and $3=p^0 \cdot 3$ we get $\nu_p(3)=0$.
Now I am stuck on calculating $\nu_p(x_0)$.

Edit 2:
By the hint in the comments, $\nu_p(x_0)=0$.
Then since $x_0$ is a solution of $x^3 =u$ we get  $f(x_0)=0 (\equiv 0 \mod p)$.
Then, by Hensel's Lemma, there exists $x$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $x \equiv x_0 \mod p$. Since already $f(x_0)=0$, we see that $x=x_0$, thus $x^3 \equiv u \mod p$.
Is this correct thus far?
The other direction:
The only thing left is to show that if $x^3 \equiv u \mod p$, then $x^3=u$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$.

From your attempt, you don’t seem to try to use Hensel’s lemma. Is it not given yet, so you’re not allowed to use it? The question can still be answered without Hensel’s lemma, but the $\impliedby$ part would be nearly trivial with it.

@X-Rui No,I can use Hensel's Lemma, I just didn't think about it.

But I do not really see how to use it here.

@X-Rui I did edit the question, now I am stuck on calculating $\nu_p(x_0)$. Do you know how to do this?

Suppose $x_0^3=u$, $\nu_p(x_0^3)=\nu_p(p^0 u)=0$. But $\nu_p(x_0^3)=3\nu_p(x_0)$, thus $\nu_p(x_0)=0$.

First, $x^{3} = p$ implies $v_p(x^3) = v_p(u) = 0  \iff v_p(x) = 0$ so $x \in \Bbb Z_{p}^\times$. So we can write $x = a_0 + a_1p + a_2p^2+\cdots$, where $a_{i}$ is an integer between $0$ and $p-1$.
Now $x^3 = u$ implies $a_0^3 \equiv u \bmod{p}$, so $x^3 = u \bmod{p}$ has a solution.
Now, the converse is also easy; if $x^3 = u \bmod{p}$ has a solution then it is also a solution in $\Bbb Z_p$.

Regarding the converse. Why does $x^3 \equiv u \mod p$, imply $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$?

Because $x \in \Bbb F_p$, and also it is a unit so you can write $x = a_0$, that is same as $x = a_0 + 0.p + 0p^2 + \cdots \in \Bbb Z_p^\times$
